# I'm currently using android studio 1.5 and I get an error for rendering

Tags: android, android-studio

[rendering error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dynfb.png)

This is an image for the error that I am getting. Please tell me what to do. I am new to android studio and android programming. (p.s - I am on win10, if it makes a difference)
Thanks!

[my styles.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clfx4.png)

Comment: please post your build.gradle(app) file content in your question..

Comment: @SumitPathak i tried changing my theme but the error is still there.

Comment: @Droidwala i've added my file content in the answer below. Check it out and let me know if theres anything I can do.

Comment: Everything looks good..not sure what is causing the rendering error..did you tried running your app on avd/phone? because this has mostly to do with rendering issue in android studio but the app should run without any issue..

Comment: put your activity layout.xml

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

**styles.xml**

```
 <resources>
     <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     </style>
 </resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Do I add the activity to the manifest file or replace the previous one??

Comment: comment them, and paste the required code in styles and manifest file respectively

Comment: It's not working. @johnrao07 it shows an error while rebuilding the project as well as the rendering is not happening still. Im using api23. Should I change that? I've been at this for 2 days and i really could use some help!

Comment: ive added an answer containing my gradle build and manifest file. Ive also edited my question details with a snapshot of my styles file. Please have a look.